# Export settings of OctoberCMS Theme

Tags: octobercms

Im trying to export my theme from OctoberCMS.
So I went to Settings->Front-end theme -> Manage and Export

The problem is that all my settings are saved in the database instead in the `static-pages.yml`, `main-menu.yaml` and so on. But the content-files are OK in the static-pages folder.

Is there are possibility to write all settings into the filesystem from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm it will be a little tricky,  there is one option you can add settings to your `theme.yaml` file and then just use them from there

> you can extend theme configuration settings which are written on `theme.yaml` file and it can be exported.

you can read the entire article and watch a video of it here
ref: [Extend And Export OctoberCMS Theme Settings](https://tutorialmeta.com/octobercms/extend-and-export-octobercms-theme-settings)

```php
<?php namespace Hardiksatasiya\So;

use System\Classes\PluginBase;
// ...

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
  public function boot() {
    \Event::listen('backend.form.extendFieldsBefore', function ($formWidget) {
      // if its not theme modal do not proceed
      if (!$formWidget->model instanceof \Cms\Classes\Theme) {
          return;
      }

      // Here you can't use addFields() because it will throw you an exception because the form is not yet created
      // and it does not have tabs and fields

      // add  navigation_text field
      $formWidget->fields['navigation_text'] = [
          'label' => 'Navigation Text',
          'comment' => 'Site should show navigation text on navigation menu.',
          'span' => 'left'

      ];

      // add another primary_color field
      $formWidget->fields['primary_color'] = [
          'label' => 'Primary Color',
          'comment' => 'Select theme primary color.',
          'type' => 'colorpicker',
          'span' => 'right'
      ];
    });
  }
  // ...
```

> field will look like this

[image: theme-field-extension]

> Your `yaml` file will look like this

```yaml
navigation_text: 'My website navigation' #new field
primary_color: '#2ecc71'                 #new field
name: Demo
description: 'Some description.'
author: OctoberCMS
homepage: 'http://octobercms.com'
code: 'hardik.satasiya'
```

> This is how `you can use these config values`

```php
use Cms\Classes\Theme;

// get your current active theme  
$theme = Theme::getActiveTheme();

// get your config value
$navigationText = $theme->getConfigValue('navigation_text', 'Default value');
$primaryColor = $theme->getConfigValue('primary_color', '#fff');

// $navigationText => 'My website navigation'
// $primaryColor => '#2ecc71'
```

if any doubt please comment.